# How to handle alert that appears anytime through out the app with objective C Unit testing in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, ios-ui-automation

I saw several questions in here about alert handling but all are described in javascript. But I need the solution in objective C. So, I know to handle an alert appears into an screen in a definite time. But how to handle alerts which are indefinite? Means, if an alert appears anytime in the application than what I will do to catch the alert?

Comment: Please share some code about how you are creating these alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can catch the alerts you need to be able to trigger them for testing purposes in a reliable way. So look at the criteria that drives the alert and figure out how to simulate it in a testing situation. Once there, you can then look at how to verify the contents of the alert and that it is appearing correctly.

If you are not using it, I would also suggest looking into how [OCMock](http://ocmock.org)  can assist. When it comes to unit testing Objective-C code, I find it to be invaluable in allowing me to hack into things and create the varying situations I need. Note though, that OCMock will not work with Swift because of the way Swift code executes. So if you are looking at Swift, your testing techniques will have to change radically.